# Passing the coefficients from a model to a function automatically

Tags: r

Consider this simple regression example with a function having two coefficients `a` and `b`:

```r
set.seed(9999)
len <- 50
x = runif(len)
y = runif(len, min = 0.9, max = 1.1) * x + runif(len, min = -0.5, max = +0.5)
df.tmp.model <- data.frame(x, y)
fn <- function(x, a, b) {
  return(a*x + b)
}
m <- nls(formula = y ~ fn(x, a, b), data = df.tmp.model, start = list(a = 1, b = 0))

integrate(fn, min(x), max(x), a = coef(m)[1], b = coef(m)[2])
#> 0.481336 with absolute error < 5.4e-15
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

I would like to try different models with different number of coefficients, so enumerating the coefficients in the integration function is not possible. Is there a way to automatically pass them as extra arguments to the `integrate` function call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `do.call`, you can programmatically call a function. This was obvious to me already, but figuring out how to create the list of arguments was not so obvious. You can simply concatenate the lists, as `coef(m)` is already a list. Neat!

It works like this:

```r
do.call(
  integrate, 
    c(
      list(
        f = fn,
        lower = min(x),
        upper = max(x)
      ),
      coef(m)
    )
)
```